Problem inspired from IMO P3 1989
Initial conditions of the Olympiad problem,
Let $n$ and $k$ be a positive integers and let $S$ be a set of $n$ points in the real plane such that,

no three points in $S$ are collinear,
For any point $P$ in $S$, there are at least $k$ points equidistant from it.

My question is: Setting $k=2$, I want to find a set of finite cardinality $n$ with above-mentioned properties and that for all possible pairs of points, $A \in S, B \in S$ there exist $P_1$ and $P_2 \in S$ such that $P_1A = P_1B$ and $P_2A=P_2B$. Using the fact that points equidistant from the endpoints of a line segment lie on its perpendicular bisector isn't helping me find a finite $n$ and arrangement of points in the plane.

Can you clarify what you mean by "($P_1$ and $P_2$) are equidistant to $A$ and $B$"?  In particular, do you want 1/ $P_1A = P_1B$ and $P_2A = P_2B$, 2/$P_1A = P_2 A$ and $P_1B = P_2B$, 3/$P_1A = P_1B = P_2B = P_2 A$?

Not possible for $n=4$. Points $P_1$ and $P_2$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $B$ and vice versa, so the points must form a rhombus. But then taking two adjacent points of the rhombus, it is not possible that the other two are on the perpendicular bisector.

@Calvin Lin Sorry for the ambiguity I have edited the question.
